# Localization .po file format

Tags: php, javascript, localization, po

I am working on web application (used PHP, javascript language) , I have provided localization support to my application. Currently supported English language.
I am supporting another languages.

I know **basic format of .po file** i.e.  :

```
msgid "Unknown login error"
msgstr “Please enter corrent credientioals"
```

**I wanted to know standard format for writing po file.**

Please suggest me, from where I will get po file standard format through with I can build good po file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/PO-Files.html

Comment: Thanks joni for your reference!

Answer (score 0):

Those are the most used tags:

`#:` = source file.

`msgid` = original string.

`msgstr` = denotes the string which to become the translation.

**Example:**

```
#: Folder/File.extension
msgid "Original String"
msgstr ""
```

[Documentation](http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html)